# Cannot invoke initializer for type 'String' with an argument list of type '(CustomObject)'

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, string

I'm trying to cast/ convert a custom object to string but keep getting the error:

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'String' with an argument list of
>   type '(ArtInfo)'

I have a custom class:

```
class ArtInfo {

  var poster: String?
  var artwork: String?
  var fanart: String?

  init (poster: String?, artwork: String?, fanart: String?){
    self.poster = poster
    self.artwork = artwork
    self.fanart = fanart
  }
}
```

After retrieving the values (json data) I'm trying to put them in local arrays.  The arrays are split up by category, the json retrieval and parsing covers all the data not just this particular class. Here is how I append the data to the local array:

```
      var photosArray: [String] = []

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad() 
        DetailShowInfo.updateAllDetails(urlExtension: url, completionHandler: { details in

      let artPics = ArtInfo.init(poster: details[0].poster, artwork: details[0].artwork, fanart: details[0].fanart)
          self.photosArray.append(String(artPics))// Error happens here
    })
}
```

Comment: What is `String(artPics)` supposed to do?

Comment: its supposed to convert the custom object 'ArtInfo' to string

Comment: *"convert"* in what way? What is the expected outcome?

Comment: take the data in ArtInfo and change it to string format

Comment: How is the program supposed to know how to compose a string of that object? Should it put the three inner variables just next to each other or reverse them, put a comma in between them, shuffle them, multiply them, sort them? *You* have to tell the program how to create a string based on *your* object.

Comment: You need to define an extension to String which specifies how to turn an ArtInfo object into a string.

Comment: I think I may have figured it out. Something like this: self.photosArray.append(String(describing: artPics.artwork))

Comment: @closetCoder, there is a protocol `CustomStringConvertible` that you can make your custom objects conform to, and then you implement a `description` Method. See my answer for an example.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? You said you want to convert `ArtInfo` to a String, but once you've done that how do you plan to use this String? If you can explain the bigger picture we'll have a better chance of getting you where you want to go. In other words, let's figure out how we can solve your actual problem instead of just getting you over the first roadblock.

Comment: Gak. Looking more closely at your code it looks like you're making a mistake. Don't convert your `artPics` object to a string and append that to an array. Just create an array of `ArtInfo` objects directly

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the function `String(describing:)`.

So you'd use `String(describing:artPics)`.

That will display a string describing any object, but the string returned is not very useful by default.

In order to get a useful string, you need to make your custom object conform to the CustomStringConvertible protocol, which means it has a `String` `description` property. Here's what your class might look like:

```
class ArtInfo: CustomStringConvertible {

  var poster: String?
  var artwork: String?
  var fanart: String?

  init (poster: String?, artwork: String?, fanart: String?){
    self.poster = poster
    self.artwork = artwork
    self.fanart = fanart
  }
  var description: String {
    return "ArtInfo object. Poster = " + 
    poster + ", artwork = " + artwork +
    ", fanart = " + fanart
  }
}
```

(Adjust the code behind your computed `description` property to get the format you want. The above would yield the rather nasty 'optional("value")' you get from optionals.)